# next.config.js images domains problem with env

Tags: javascript, reactjs, configuration, next.js, environment-variables

I have a problem with the next.config.js images domains.

Here is the next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
 reactStrictMode: true,

 env: {
  CLIENT_LOCAL_API_URL: '/api',
  CLIENT_API_URL: '/api'
 }, 
 serverRuntimeConfig: {
  SERVER_API_URL: process.env.SERVER_API_URL
 },
 images: {
  domains: [process.env.IMAGE_DOMAIN],
 },
}
```

Here is the .env file

```
SERVER_API_URL = api-url
IMAGE_DOMAIN = img-domain
```

I can't run the app.
I get this error after npm run dev:

> Specified images.domains should be an Array of strings received invalid values ()

I don't get it where I am doing wrong

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it. The env file name was *.env.example.* I changed to *.env.local*